# iterating elements of dictionaries sequentially using single loop

Tags: python

Consider dictionaries like:

```
a_dict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
b_dict = {"A":5,"B":6,"C":7}
for (k,v),(k1,v1) in zip(a_dict.items(),b_dict.items())):  
    print(k,v);
    print(k1,v1);
```

output

```
b 2
B 6
a 1
A 5
c 3
C 7
```

After searching about dictionary i got that the elements of dictionaries are not sorted that's why these elements of dictionaries are printed randomly. But i want them printed sequentially. that is

```
a 1
A 5
b 2
B 6
c 3
C 7
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on how you want them sorted. The answer using `chain` below sorts *all* the element by the lowercase version of the key (which may be what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve data as you stored, you have to use `OrderedDict` since `dictionaries` doesn't keep data as it is inserted.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a_dict=OrderedDict((k, v) for k,v in [["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]])
b_dict=OrderedDict((k, v) for k,v in [["A",5],["B",6],["C",7]])

for (k,v),(k1,v1) in zip(a_dict.items(),b_dict.items()):
    print(k,v);
    print(k1,v1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chaining](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and sorting:

```
from itertools import chain

a_dict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
b_dict = {"A":5,"B":6,"C":7}

for key, value in sorted(chain(a_dict.items(), b_dict.items()), 
                         key=lambda x: x[0].lower()):
    print(key, value)
```

Prints:

```
a 1
A 5
b 2
B 6
c 3
C 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make order for both dicts with `sorted()`, like this:

```
a_dict = {"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3}
b_dict = {"A": 5,"B": 6,"C": 7}
for (k,v), (k1,v1) in zip(sorted(a_dict.items()), sorted(b_dict.items())):
    print(k,v)
    print(k1,v1)
```

Output:

```
a 1
A 5
b 2
B 6
c 3
C 7
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated sorting you can also use OrderedDict from collections module.